# Getting a 404 null error with Angular 7 [src] attribute

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to load an image using `[src]` attribute in Angular application. The image content renders fine outside when i load it up directly. However, with the app it gives me 404 null error.

HTML -

```
<span class="pull-right">
        <img
          [src]="sampleImage"
          alt="{{ user.firebaseuser.displayName }}"
          class="img-responsive"
          style="max-height: 50px;">
</span>
```

Component class -

```
export class UserItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() user: any;
  // @Input() index: number;

  sampleImage = 'https://americana-group.com/app/uploads/2017/11/koki1920x960-1048x524.jpg';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Error Details -

```
http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found)
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Can you recreate this in Stackblitz? I have test the above code and it is perfectly working in my app

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zv15qu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: this ``alt="{{ user.firebaseuser.displayName }}"`` is what's probably breaking your code.

Answer (score 4):

Use `[attr.src]="..."` instead. It won't add a `src` if the value is null and will stop the localhost from calling `null`.